# Why don't we have the "general reference" close option?

Tags: support, close-reasons

EL&U has among its reasons for a close vote "general reference".  I wanted to vote to close [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/what-parsha-is-the-most-commonly-read-parsha) for that reason, but it doesn't appear on our list.  Should it, or did EL&U do something special to get it?

Comment: What type of questions would you like to close with this reason?

Comment: I don't know how common it would be.  In this case the question could be answered by consulting the torah readings in the back of the siddur.  (So I followed the crowd to "not constructive", but that didn't feel quite right, which got me wondering.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I may have used it here. He knew the phrase that he wanted. If had put it into google the correct source would have popped up instantly. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16242/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [a blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) that introduced this closure reason and explained that it was under consideration, and [a later MSO answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88521) that described its implmentation on EL&U (and SciFi) and said (among other interesting things) "It is unlikely we will ever adopt this close reason network wide".

Comment: Thanks!  Ok, I'd buy that.  And if I haven't been prompted to ask the question until now, after more than a year of participation, it's probably pretty rare here.